# JComboBox Not Refreshing/Updating Because of ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

So here's my problem: I'm currently using two JComboBoxes. The second JComboBox is suppose to update depending on what is selected in the first JComboBox. In this case, the first JComboBox holds the initials of a major of study: (ART, CSC, MTH, PHY, etc..) and the second JComboBox is suppose to update to all possible class numbers that exist for that specific major.  So the filereader I have is able to read all the information and fill in both lists accordingly.  The first problem I had was making the second JComboBox update when specific majors were selected from the first JComboBox.  I fixed this by adding an actionListener to thefirst JComboBox. But now I have another problem..:

**PROBLEM:** When I click the first JComboBox there is a list of all the majors like there should be but when I click one of the majors, it won't change.  The second JComboBox will change appropriately as if I selected the right one, but the first JComboBox won't change.  It just stays at "ART" (First in the list alphabetically).

I select one of the other options from the first JComboBox:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/problem2t.jpg/

It changes the second JComboBox appropriately but the first one doesn't change.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/problem1n.jpg/

Here is my code: First I have my constructor that sets up the graphics. Then I have my action listener(the JComboBox is the last elseif-statement), then I have my method that sets up the JComboBoxes.

```
public Student(){
        //Window Attributes
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Academic Major Selection");

        //Center the Program Window
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(toolkit.getScreenSize());
        setLocation((int)dim.getWidth()/2 - WINDOW_WIDTH/2,(int)dim.getHeight()/2 - WINDOW_HEIGHT/2);

        //do not allow resizing of window
        setResizable(false);

        //create arrays for classes
        //input file reader here
        String[] subjectArray = {"CSC","MTH","ENG","THE","PHY"};
        String[] numberArray = {"100","200","300","400","500"};


        //create boxes for dropdown
        subjectBox = new JComboBox(subjectArray);
        subjectBox.addActionListener(this);
        numberBox = new JComboBox(numberArray);

        //creates a panel for our dropdown panels
        selectPanel = new JPanel();
        selectPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,25,0));
        selectPanel.add(subjectBox);
        selectPanel.add(numberBox);
            .
            .
            .//trimmed out some excess stuff
            .
        try {
            setDropDownBoxes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //show the window
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //What button is pressed?
        .
            .
            .//Trimmed out some extra stuff
            .
            //This will equal true when something is selected from the first JComboBox
        }else if(((String)subjectBox.getSelectedItem()).length() == 3){
            System.out.println("New Subject Selected");
            try {
                setDropDownBoxes();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    void setDropDownBoxes() throws IOException{
        int j=0;

        String[][] someArrayTwoD = studentWriter.fetchClassLists();

        String[] subjectArray = new String[someArrayTwoD.length];
        while(j<someArrayTwoD.length){
            subjectArray[j] = someArrayTwoD[j][0];
            j++;
        }

        String[] numberArray = new String[someArrayTwoD[subjectBox.getSelectedIndex()].length-1];
        for(int i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++){
            numberArray[i] = someArrayTwoD[subjectBox.getSelectedIndex()][i+1];
        }   

        selectPanel.remove(subjectBox);
        selectPanel.remove(numberBox);

        subjectBox = new JComboBox(subjectArray);
        numberBox = new JComboBox(numberArray);

        selectPanel.add(subjectBox);
        selectPanel.add(numberBox);
        selectPanel.validate();
        subjectBox.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code, most if it not relevant to the problem at hand which means that it only serves to confuse us. Consider paring down your code a bit so that it only contains code relevant to the problem plus a little bit of code to allow it to be a self-sufficient small compilable and runnable program, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry about that. I've trimmed it down to more relevant code.  Since it depends on a lot of other stuff I'm not sure how self-sufficient I can make it. I'll try to make it a small runable program if I can though.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your code is that you're using `==` to check for String equivalence rather than use either the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method:

```
if(e.getActionCommand() == addButton.getText()){
    //....
}
```

Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if (fu.equals("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if (fu.equalsIgnoreCase("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

Or even better, get rid of your "switch-board" ActionListener, don't have your GUI class implement listener interfaces (generally a bad idea), and instead give your JButtons anonymous inner class listeners.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that.  That part was actually wrote by someone else working on the program with me and looking back on it I'm surprised any of those if-statements worked at all.  I've changed them all to .equals() but the problem persists. I'll add pictures soon.

Comment: @Wakko45: if you seriously need our help, again consider putting in the effort to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check the link.